# Php - Interface method with unknown number of parameters

Tags: php, oop, interface

Suppose I have several classes with a method

```
public function foo (int $a, int $b, ..) {..}
```

where the number of parameters depends on the particular class (but is fixed for a specific class).

Is there a way to put such a method in an interface so that all my classes could implement that interface?

I don't think variadics can help here, because I would need to define all my `foo` implementations as

```
public function foo(int ...$ints) {..}
```

losing the information around how many parameters I need to have for a specific class.

Any trickery that could be used?

P.S. I would really like to avoid exceptions, so I can't just check if the number of arguments matches programmatically

Comment: Pass an array of params instead of individual params.

Comment: @BSB that's what you have using variadics. Bit you lose the information of how many parameters are needed by every single class

Comment: Couldn't understand fully. But if you want number of parameters passed, You can count params array Indexes.

Comment: I could do that, but what if the number is wrong? I would like to force the client of my class to pass the correct number of arguments

Answer (score 2):

There is no way of achieving that without using something like `func_num_args` or `count($ints)` and throwing an exception on failure.

This also seems like a potential design flaw.

If you really need an interface and your parameter is a set of values, I would really recommend receiving an array and checking number and type of items in that array.

Comment: I guess an Interface is too restrictive for my purpose. Still, I don't think at this point that there is a way to communicate that my classes have a too method receiving a certain number of integers

Answer (score 2):

If parameters differ, while the method's name is the same, then it is not the same interface. It's simple as that.

You are trying to put a round peg in a square hole.

Comment: yeah, an interface is too much here. What I could do is having an empty interface, just to name things. Or many interfaces, one per number of arguments. Still, these are not nice solutions

Comment: Instead of having each parameter separate, you could pass in an instance instead.

Comment: No idea why the downvote here, this is perfectly correct. An interface is to make a contract with some specific methods and their params and return type. If the params are different, then you are creating objects with different values, which makes them different objects. if `UserClassA` can have property "name" as string or null, and `UserClassB` property "name" cannot be null, they are not to be interfaced objects.